# How to get rid of white space around ggplot2 map

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, border, borderless

How can I get rid of the white space around an image? Say that I have this code:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)
mp <- openmap(c(28,-115), c(50,-67),zoom=6,'stamen-watercolor')
states_map <- map_data("state") %>% filter(lat > 28 & lat < 50 & long > -115 & long < -67)
states_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(states_map$lat,states_map$long))
states_map_merc$group <- states_map$group
counties_map <- map_data("county") %>% filter(lat > 28 & lat < 50 & long > -115 & long < -67)
counties_map_merc <- as.data.frame(projectMercator(counties_map$lat,counties_map$long))
counties_map_merc$group <- counties_map$group

a <- OpenStreetMap::autoplot.OpenStreetMap(mp,expand=FALSE) + 
    geom_polygon(data=states_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.7) + 
    geom_polygon(data=counties_map_merc, aes(x=x,y=y,group=group), fill="black",colour="white",alpha=0, size=.2) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.caption = element_text(size=11)) +
    geom_text(x=-10018754, y=3299499, label="Text.") +
    expand_limits(x=0, y=0) +
    scale_x_continuous(0) +
    scale_y_continuous(0)
ggsave(a, filename="map_static2.png")
```

This produces:

[image]

The white space bordering this map is undesirable. How can I get rid of it? In other words, I want to have the borders of the image be the tan edges of the map, not white space.

Note that this question relates to this one ([How to make area saved with ggsave smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398518/how-to-make-area-saved-with-ggsave-smaller)). I tried what @MrFlick suggested by adding the `expand_limits`, `scale_x_continuous`, and `scale_y_continuous` lines, but they didn't seem to do anything.

UPDATE: Instead of the final four lines, I used:

```
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) 
ggsave(a, filename="map_static3.png", width=8, height=4.64)
```

And it fixed it. The https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945857/2204410 link from @Jaap was it.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945857/2204410

Comment: Your code produces a map unadorned by any frames.  So that makes me think you're displaying the map via a web page or app.  Given the map itself is frameless, that suggests that the frame - and whitespace - is being added by HTML or similar.  So we need to see a reproducible example.  This isn't one yet.

Comment: @Limey, I took a screenshot due to the file size limit of StackOverflow. That is why the image looks the way it does. The `ggsave` command produces the above image without the gray borders. 

Am I understanding your meaning?

Comment: Yes. Your code produces a plot with no borders. Try it!

Comment: I tried it and it still had borders. But I modified it using the idea from @Jaaps answer and it works. See the solution in the question.

Thanks for the help!